# Помогите обновить ID firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebase, firebird, firebase-database

Добрый день помогите проблема заключаеться в том что у меня есть таблица в которой есть поле ID которое автоматичесикй генерирует новый ID от 0 до 2758 записей,мне нужно добавить данные с другой базы но там много ID совпадающих как обновить все поля ID ?
(сейчас самый первый ID начинаеться с 994 надо его отчет сделать с 1)

[image: бАЗА]

Comment: вручную вписать новые записи займет очень много времений так как одна таблца имеет около 1000 полей функия извлечи данные или обновить не помогло

Comment: Запрос UPDATE не поможет?..

Comment: UPDATE тут должен быть такой хитровыкрученный... Тут скорее целую процедуру писать нужно.

Comment: Да нет, если FK нет, то просто SET USERID=GEN_ID(anything, 1). Если FK есть, то проще "данные из другой базы" с новыми ID импортировать.